# Login post request with jQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http, bots

I'm trying to write a bot to log in and checkout automatically on the https://zalando.it site (is the same in other languages), but i don't understand how to write a request like this in ajax (this is the login form):
[image]

Payload is like 3 elements "email, secret and request".
This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    alert("ciao");
    $.post("https://accounts.zalando.com/api/login",
    {
      email: "myemail",
      request: "eyJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiJmYXNoaW9uLXN0b3JlLXdlYiIsInJlc3BvbnNlX3R5cGUiOiJjb2RlIiwic2NvcGVzIjpbIm9wZW5pZCJdLCJyZWRpcmVjdF91cmkiOiJodHRwczovL3d3dy56YWxhbmRvLml0L3Nzby9jYWxsYmFjayIsInN0YXRlIjoiZXlKdmNtbG5hVzVoYkY5eVpYRjFaWE4wWDNWeWFTSTZJbWgwZEhCek9pOHZkM2QzTG5waGJHRnVaRzh1YVhRdmRXOXRieTFvYjIxbEx5SXNJblJ6SWpvaU1qQXlNUzB4TVMweE9GUXhNRG93T0RveE9Wb2lmUT09Iiwibm9uY2UiOiIyNzQ2NmEyYi1iNWUyLTQ0MGItYmU0NS1iM2QwYjk1YmY5N2IiLCJ1aV9sb2NhbGVzIjpbIml0LUlUIl0sInJlcXVlc3RfaWQiOiJ6Rmt1a0dXRDJ5b1EyMHJVOmNkYTFhZDQ5LTZlMjMtNDE5Ny1iNjA0LTZiYjM5MDY1ZjY1MDpFLTB3dXZjVTB2aTNhV0ZpIn0=",
      secret: "mypassword"
    },
    function(data,status){
      alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
  });
});
```

It returns a 403 status code. Why?

Comment: i can see the return status is 203, can you post the response?

Comment: Have you follow all [documention](https://opensource.zalando.com/restful-api-guidelines/)?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini I am just working on this login for Zalando. I even copied the login request's cUrl and pasted it in Postman but it still returns with status code 403. In response headers you can see that the server is AkamaiNetStorage which I guess is some kind of bot protection. Do you maybe know how to get around this?